# Multiple floating divs with no space between them

Tags: html, css

I have these `div`s with variable content created dynamically, they are all governed by the same CSS rules. I want them to be placed in 2 columns with no space in between them, I tried using `float: left/right` but that still leaves space in the top and bottom.

This is a sample code (you can also see it on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u51vpaw0/)):

```css
.posts{
  width: 100%;
}

.one{
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}

.two{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 120px;
  width: 40%;
  float: left;  
}
```

```html
<div class="posts">
  <div class="one">
  </div>
  <div class="two">
  </div>
  <div class= "two">
  </div>
  <div class ="one">
  </div>
</div>
```

So in that example, the right `div` boxes are fine, but they create a space between the top left box and the bottom `div`. I tried looking up some simple examples, but all of them suggest modifying the `div`s separately with `overflow: hidden`, and other options.

What is the best way to do it with **all** the `div`s sharing the same CSS?

Comment: class `.one` is `height: 100px`, while class `.two` is `height: 120px`, that is why you are getting the extra space of 20px.

Comment: Yes i know, its from tumblr. I dont have control over individual content inside the divs, but they are all governed by the same css. In my example I am using different heights as an example of 2 posts with different heights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning**: If the browsers you want to support do not support [columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns), this will not work and may still not be the right solution for you:

What you are trying to do is create a [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html#imagesloaded) style layout.

This should do what you want:

```css
.container {
            column-count: 2;
       -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
            column-gap: 0;
       -moz-column-gap: 0;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0;
    width: 80%;
    font-size: 0;
}

.container div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;
}

.container .one {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

.container .two {
    height: 120px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="one">one</div>
    <div class="two">two</div>
    <div class="two">two</div>
    <div class="one">one</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you for your help, and sorry if my question was a bit vague at first

Comment: @JorgeLazo It's ok, sometimes asking questions can be just as difficult as answering them.

Answer (score 0):

Does this accomplish what you are trying to do?

```css
.posts{
    width: 100%;
}
.one,
.two {
    height: 100px;
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
}
.one{
    background-color: red;
}
.two{
    background-color: blue;   
}
```

```html
<div class="posts">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="one"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, it does not. The content inside the divs are added dynamically, making them with different heights. I dont have control of what specific div will have what content, I can only control the global css for all divs. In my example i coded the heights differently on purpose. I want the divs to float next to each other but with no spacing between them.

Comment: @JorgeLazo I believe I understand now what you are trying to do, please see my 2nd answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34584404/1427800

Answer (score 0):

Make your code like this,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.posts{
    width: 50%;
     float:left;
}
.one{
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    width:100%;
}
.two{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 120px;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="posts">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
</div>
<div class="posts">
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="one"></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its really close, but the 4 sub divs need to be inside the posts div, otherwise its just a single column. Is there any way to do it like that?

Comment: i think thats is the best solution,